# localeCompare() strings containing "1" and "-1" in different browsers

Tags: javascript, sorting

I've noticed the following differences in return values when comparing strings containing `"-1"`, `"1"` and `"0"` using `String.prototype.localeCompare()` in Chrome and Edge:

```
"1".localeCompare("-1");
// Edge: -1, Chrome: 1

"0".localeCompare("-1")
// Edge: -1, Chrome: 1

"-1".localeCompare("1")
// Edge: 1, Chrome: -1
```

1. Why is there a difference in return values between the browsers?
2. Is there a way to have browsers behave consistently in the scenarios
   above?

Comment: i think  you have different settings on the browsers , try to use the second arguments of the localCompare method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Parameters

Comment: I have so far failed to find any locales or options that makes localCompare() return consistent values across browsers in the mentioned scenarios.

Comment: Backward duplicate, but that's the direction that was available. :-)

Comment: I'm guessing that was the only available direction because that question received an answer.